# Mackey and weak and weak* topology and all that

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $U$ be a Banach space with topological dual space $U^\ast$. Denote by $\sigma(U^\ast,U)$ the weak*, by $\sigma(U^\ast, U^{\ast\ast})$ the weak and by $\tau(U^\ast,U)$ the Mackey topology on $U^\ast$ w.r.t. $U$ and by $\tau(U^\ast,U^{\ast\ast})$ the Mackey topology on $U^\ast$ w.r.t. $U^{\ast\ast}$ . Is it true that 
$$
 \sigma(U^\ast,U)\subseteq \tau(U^\ast,U)\subseteq \sigma(U^\ast, U^{\ast\ast})\subseteq \tau(U^\ast,U^{\ast\ast})? 
$$
The first and third inclusion are true due to the Mackey-Arens theorem (and in the case of Banach spaces we anyway have that $\tau(U^\ast, U^{\ast\ast})$ equals the norm open sets in $U^\ast$) . But how do you argue for the second inclusion? Note, that the Mackey-Arens theorem only implies $\sigma(U^\ast, U^{\ast\ast})\not\subseteq  \tau(U^\ast,U)$?